# RecyclerView doesnot scroll when not nested in NestedScrollView but is in the same LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using the following layout, but unable to get the RecyclerView to scroll(it is not visible on the screen when using this layout, scrolling stops till the NestedScrollView).

I can scroll up to the NestedScrollView and the CollapsingToolbar to collapse, if I remove the entire NestedScrollView then I get the RecyclerView to scroll.

If I keep the linear layout without the NestedScrollView,  only the RecyclerView  scrolls, the rest of the layout is fixed.

I have also added `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the RecyclerView, and have kept the RecyclerView out of the NestedScrollView.

If I add the RecyclerView inside the NestedScrollView, the RecyclerView does not appear.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.MainFragment">

    <!-- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout here
         with a android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    -->

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <!-- more layout code here -->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"/>

                </RelativeLayout>



                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewListOfData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by nesting `RecyclerView` inside the `NestedScrollView` and updating the support library for `recyclerview`

I was using `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1`

as of Android Support Library, revision 23.2.0 (February 2016)
[(refer revision archive here)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive#rev23-2-0)

> Changes for v7 RecyclerView library:
>
> RecyclerView now has an opt-in feature called AutoMeasure which allows RecyclerView.LayoutManager to easily wrap content or
>   handle various measurement specifications provided by the parent of
>   the RecyclerView. It supports all existing animation capabilities of
>   the RecyclerView.
>
> If you have a custom RecyclerView.LayoutManager, call setAutoMeasureEnabled(true) to start using the new AutoMeasure API.
>   All built-in RecyclerView.LayoutManager objects enable auto-measure by
>   default.
>
> RecyclerView.LayoutManager no longer ignores some RecyclerView.LayoutParams settings, such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll
>   direction.
>
> **Note: These lifted restrictions may cause unexpected behavior in your
>   layouts. Make sure you specify the correct layout**
>   parameters.

Using `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0` solves the problem of nested recyclerview not appearing in nested scroll view

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to add `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` add this line into RecyclerView in xml file `app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"`.

> Example

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/your_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Then in your `SomeActivity.java` file where you populate `RecyclerView` put this line `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` before you setting adapter to `RecyclerView`.

> Example

```
RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: If I add the `RecyclerView ` inside the `NestedScrollView` the `RecyclerView ` is not populated

Comment: @John, Sorry for late answer. if you just show how you populating your `RecyclerView`, I could be more helpful. Well, I mean edit your question and add some code from your project (if possible) where you initialize your `RecyclerView`( this line `RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview);`) and populate it (this line`recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);`)